# What privilege need to read a file in module database

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a configuration file in Marklogic modules database and what is the privilege needed for doing this

```
xdmp:invoke-function(function(){fn:doc('/config/context.xml')},<options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>{xdmp:modules-database()}</database></options>)
```

I am setting the following privileges

- unprotected-collections
- unprotected-uri
- unprotected-collections
- unprotected-uri
- xdmp:spawn
- xdmp:spawn-in
- xdmp:spawn-transaction
- xdmp:http-get
- xdmp:http-head
- xdmp:http-options
- xdmp:http-delete
- xdmp:http-post
- xdmp:http-put
- xdmp:eval
- xdmp:eval-in
- xdmp:spawn-transaction
- xdmp:invoke
- xdmp:invoke-in
- xdmp:invoke-modules-change
- xdmp:invoke-modules-change-file
- xdmp:invoke-transaction
- xdmp:xslt-eval
- xdmp:xslt-eval-in
- xdmp:xslt-eval-transaction
- xdmp:load
- xdmp:xslt-invoke
- xdmp:xslt-invoke-in
- xdmp:xslt-invoke-transaction

what other privileges I am missing, as if I login as rest-admin or admin everything works ??

Comment: Are you sure you're executing that statement as the user with those privileges? What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting no error.. all I get is empty.. but when I give the user "rest-admin" role, I can read it. so I was assuming I am missing some privilege that I am not assigning

Comment: Ah, okay...are you sure that `/config/context.xml` is assigned a role with read permission that the user reading the document also has?

Comment: The `/config/context.xml` is in modules database, and I loaded using ml-gradle, and I loaded other library files as well in the modules database, the user was able to execute the library calls.. do I need to give 'read' as well to the privilege, for the `kind` I gave only `execute`.. could this be the reason for not able to read the file ?

Comment: Yes. Unless the user is admin, the document must have `read` permission for a role that the user also has.

Comment: Yeah once in my gradle configuration I gave permission of rest-reader it worked.. Thanks, I will update with answer for specific gradle configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was loading all the modules database (which included `/config/context.xml`) using ml-gradle. By default ml-gradle will load all the modules with `rest-admin,read,rest-admin,update,rest-extension-user,execute`

But it turns out we can overwrite [(ML-Gradle:Make it easy to override module permissions)](https://github.com/rjrudin/ml-gradle/issues/27)  it using `mlModulePermissions`

Following is what I did in my `gradle.properties` file

```
mlModulePermissions=rest-admin,read,rest-admin,update,rest-extension-user,execute,rest-reader
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Ravi found the missing link himself, but for the sake of completeness:

That list of privileges is far too long. To be allowed to run `xdmp:invoke-function` with a non-admin user (also sometimes referenced as a **least-privs** user) the user only needs the `xdmp:invoke` privilege. To be allowed to use the `<database>` option of that function, you need the additional `xdmp:eval-in` privilege. The required privileges are usually very well documented on DMC. See for instance: http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eval

But regardless of the privileges you grant a user, it still needs to have a role that has `read` access to the documents it is trying to read. Otherwise it will simply not see them. Assigning `rest-admin` role to a user just for the purpose of reading a config file is probably a bit too much. Assigning `rest-reader` role, and adding a document permission that grants `read` access for that role is better. Best though is probably to create an application-specific role, assign that to the user, and add a `read` document permission for that role.

HTH!